# Playing movie in iOS applicatione made in Flex

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, ios, ipod

I'm writing the application for iOS in Flex (sdk 4.5). Is it possible to play movie in such built application?

I was trying to use Video component - which works well on my desktop, but it doesn't work on my iPod. Of course my application is running, but the video isn't playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have final results:
It is possible to play video in iOS app written for AIR 2.6 but it can't be decoded by using h.264 video and acc audio codecs.

For me it was working when video was decoded by using vp6 codec and standard Video component. There is an issue with low frame rate which can be partially resolved when setting renderMode to gpu in descriptor file, however as you can see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac6c9d409a12e26b451be-8000) it's not recommended.

P.S. Thanks for help J_A_X.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that instead of trying to play the video internal to your application, you just link to it and let the native OS handle it.  The OS will either open up a browser to play the file or launch a native app to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The point is, that it _must_ be inside the app. App should capture selected frames and trace user's interaction.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com how would you, for example, place a link on a button that would just ask the OS to play a video?

Comment: @jlehenbauer use NavigateToURL w/ a URLRequest that contains the link.

Comment: @jlehenbauer In that case; I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the StageVideo class?  It's new in 10.2 and meant to utilize full hardware acceleration.  Follow [this tutorial](http://corlan.org/2010/12/01/working-with-stage-video/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I have. For me it was working only for web application. It wasn't working for AIR applications. There wasn't any error, simply movie wasn't loaded.

Comment: Darn, apparently, it's only [available for Android honeycomb (tablets)](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/895/cpsid_89556.html).  What you should do is have a fallback, or just use the normal Video class until it's available for your phone.

Comment: I wish. Video class doesn't work on iOS as well (it works in debug mode on desktop however).

Comment: After doing some research, it's apparently impossible to do on iOS just yet, but I [found an alternative](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/air-2-6-for-ios-and-video-playback/) which might be adequate for your purposes.

Comment: So we have an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid, that solution from this [article](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/air-2-6-for-ios-and-video-playback/)  doesn't seem to work. '<video>' tag isn't supported by StageWebView.

Comment: Are you sure?  The tutorial specifically says it works.  Are you using Air 2.6?